# javascript function won't loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here is a piece of a javascript practice problem that I am working on:

```
function combo(str){
  var splitStr=str.split("");
  for (var i=0; i<splitStr.length; i++){
    return splitStr[i];
  }
}

console.log(combo("dog"));
```

Why won't the loop return all three letters? It prints "d" and stops. If I take the loop out of the function, it works.

What am I doing wrong? Please explain.

Comment: Why would it, you can only return from the function once, and once that is done, it doesn't keep on running magically in the background and return more stuff.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return` ends the invocation of the function, giving you back whatever is after that `return`

Your code structure looks like you wanted it to act like `yield` but ES5- does not support this so you can't use it (yet), and you would still have other problems (i.e. you'd be logging just the first generated result)

Instead, pass your `console.log` (bound to `console`) into a the loop;

```
function combo(str, callback){
    var splitStr=str.split("");
    for (var i=0; i<splitStr.length; i++){
        callback(splitStr[i]);
    }
}

combo('dog', console.log.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from inside the for loop and this ceases the function's execution. If you want to return each letter of the array, just return the split array itself:

```
function combo(str) {
  return str.split("");
}
```

The behavior you seem to want is somehow achievable using [generator function (function*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

```
function* combo(){
  var splitStr = str.split("");
  for (var i=0; i < splitStr.length; i++){
    yield splitStr[i];
  }
}
```

Then you'd invoke it like this:

```
var generator = combo("dog");

console.log(generator.next()) //d
console.log(generator.next()) //o
console.log(generator.next()) //g
```

Please note, however, that so far only few browser support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

With return you will end the function and come out of it with that data, next things wont be called

You can return an array instead like this.

```
function combo(str){
  return splitStr=str.split("");

}

console.log(combo("dog"));
```

Answer (score 0):

return stops the execution of the function. The rest of the loop is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

'return' within the loop ends the loop and returns the first value, since it allowed the loop to run only once.

putting the 'return' statement outside of the scope {} of the loop will allow the loop to continue to run/repeat.